# Junit test cases for StreamSupport

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am new to test cases I tried several ways to write test case for below piece of code but I never succeeded. How to write junit test case for below code using Powermockito?

```
StreamSupport.stream(irSet.spliterator(), false)
            .filter(iResultRow -> iResultRow !=null)
            .mapToInt(iResultRow ->{
                String event = iResultRow.get("STF_TY_GH");
                return StringUtils.isNotBlank(event) ? Integer.parseInt(event) : 1;
            }).findFirst().orElse(1);
```

Comment: Refactor your code to take the stream as a parameter, then pass in any stream you like in your tests.

Answer (score 3):

While, using a descent amount of mocks you can mock every single call, let me suggest you an alternative approach.

So you have a stream produced out of some input set (`irSet`) variable. This stream makes "some" processing and returns an integer result.

So if you "imagine" Its a black box: a kind of function that looks like this:

```
int doSomething(Set<SomeRow> irSet) {
  ... your implementation is here...
}
```

In this case, you might want to test what it does by supplying the various input sets and expecting for some outputs. What if there are `null`-s in the input? Will it fail or filter out what's needed. What if the set is empty? What if there is `SomeRow` that really has `STF_TY_GH` data, what if the set doesn't have such a row?

Here is a test for example:

```
  @Test
  public void test_rows_with_null_are_processed_correctly() {

      // setup:
      Set<SomeRow> input = ...// prepare a set with null values

      // when:
      Integer actual = underTest.doSomething(input)

      // then:
      // verify this "actual" whether it should be 1 or something else 
  }
```

All-in-all, use mocks only for interactions (with something you can't really instantiate like DB API/remote HTTP calls) or for something that is not related to the tested code and is used as a dependency the tested code interacts with. After all, the goal of unit tests is to test your code (the implementation of `doSomething` in this case and not to mock everything out).